# does H2 database support scrolling

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I am trying to use scrolling to iterate through all records of a table.
The code and query are really simple.

```
// a really really simple query
String hql = "from " + MyTable.class.getSimpleName();

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

// An exception is caused here
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

// My code would have continued by iterating the results
while (results.next()) { ... }
```

But this results in a `GenericJDBCException` : **"could not execute query using scroll"**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query using scroll
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2632)
  at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.scroll(QueryLoader.java:557)
  at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.scroll(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:408)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performScroll(HQLQueryPlan.java:268)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.scroll(SessionImpl.java:1346)
  at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.scroll(QueryImpl.java:89)
  ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid value "-2147483648" for parameter "rows" [90008-172]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getInvalidValueException(DbException.java:215)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.setFetchSize(JdbcStatement.java:399)
  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setFetchSize(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1722)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1886)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2595)
  ... 15 more
```

Is it possible that H2 databases don't support scrolling, or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line is a mistake:

```
query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

The value `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, is a trick to tell JDBC to use streaming. But this trick is (only) supported by MySQL, not by H2.

From [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` **serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row.** After this, any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

The stack trace shows the exception *"an invalid value `-2147483648` for parameter rows."* This value is exactly -2^31 (= `Integer.MIN_VALUE`). H2 does not know how to deal with negative fetch sizes and throws an exception.

**Conclusion: scrolling works fine for H2 databases.**

Comment: I dont see where this trick would help with any database. The idea of fetchSize is to reduce roundtrips to the database. You almost always want that.

Comment: @eckes I provided a quote from the MySQL documentation.

Comment: @bvdb You're saying "Conclusion: scrolling works fine for H2 databases." but can you explain how do it with H2?

Comment: @BjörnJacobs just remove the line of `setFetchSize(...)`. The remaining code should work fine.